# Google Scripts automatically add date to column in Google Sheets

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I am trying to use a Google script that retrieves 2 securities fields from `GOOGLEFINANCE` and saves the output to a Google Sheet file. I need the script to also add the datetime to the first column of the Sheet.

I have created a basic Google Sheet with 3 columns:

1. A is formatted to DateTime. It has column name **date** in row 1 and is empty in rows 2 onwards
2. C has the column name **price** in row 1 and is empty in rows 2 onwards
3. D has the column name **pe** in row 1 and is empty in rows 2 onwards

Here is my function:

```
function myStocks() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  sh.insertRowAfter(1);
  sh.getRange("A2").setValue(new Date());

  sh.getRange("C2").setFormula('=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price")');
  sh.getRange("D2").setFormula('=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "pe")');
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Date                    price   pe
12/10/2017 22:44:31     1037.05 34.55
12/10/2017 22:43:24     1037.05 34.55
```

The output of columns C and D is correct. The output of column A is wrong. Every time I run the function, each new row is added ABOVE the last row:

1. The first time I ran the function was at `12/10/2017 22:43:24` and it added that row first.
2. The second time I ran the function was `12/10/2017 22:44:31` BUT it added that row ABOVE the last row in the sheet - I wanted it to add the new row BELOW the last row.

Is there a way to auto fill the datetime downwards in a single column in GoogleSheets, using a script function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

#### Modification points :

- `sh.insertRowAfter(1)` means that a row is inserted between 1 row and 2 row.

  - In your situation, you can retrieve the last row using `getLastRow()`.
- `getRange("A2").setValue()`, `getRange("C2").setFormula()` and `getRange("D2").setFormula()` mean that the values are imported to "A2", "C2" and "D2", respectively.

  - By this, the values are always imported to 2 row.
- When you want to import several values and formulas to sheet, you can use `setValues()` and `setFormulas()`.

The script which was reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function myStocks() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = sh.getLastRow() + 1; // This means a next row of last row.
  sh.getRange(lastrow, 1).setValue(new Date());
  var formulas = [['=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price")', '=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "pe")']];
  sh.getRange(lastrow, 3, 1, 2).setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

#### Note :

- In your script, date and 2 formulas are imported, simultaneously. The modified script works the same to this.

#### References :

- [insertRowAfter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowAfter(Integer))
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Can you explain these 2 lines: `sh.getRange(lastrow, 1).setValue(new Date());` and `sh.getRange(lastrow, 3, 1, 2).setFormulas(formulas);` - what is the meaning of the numbers `3, 1, 2` here?

Comment: @W R I'm sorry for the inconvenience. ``sh.getRange(lastrow, 1).setValue(new Date());`` means that it imports a value of ``new Date()`` to last row + 1 at Column A. ``sh.getRange(lastrow, 3, 1, 2).setFormulas(formulas);`` means that it imports 2 formulas to last row + 1 at Column C and D. ``lastrow, 3, 1, 2`` of ``getRange(lastrow, 3, 1, 2)`` are row, column of coordinate, the number of rows and columns, respectively. The reference of ``getRange()`` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns).